# How to check what a randomized list chose?

Tags: c#, list, random

I have a randomized list of colors set up. There are 4 colors in the list.

Every time the "ball" gameObject collides with this gameObject, the color randomizes. I just want to set the tag of the gameObject to whatever color it randomizes to. In order to do that, I first need to check what the randomizer chose in the list and I'm not sure how to do that.

This video shows the randomize list code I used in full:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Xx6ghSk668

```
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "ball")
    {
        Color c = TintColors[Random.Range(0, TintColors.Count)];
           //scoretext++ (< haven't set this up yet. Ignore this)
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = c;
           //When you score, the color randomizes again

           //Not sure what to do here v
        if (TintColors(1))
           //Not sure what to do here ^
           //If the randomizer chose blue (1 being the 
           // first element in the list)
           //So I can change the gameoject tag to "blue"
        {
            transform.gameObject.tag = "blue";
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Please post all relevant code in your question so that it's self-contained and doesn't require us to watch a youtube video for context.

Comment: Your code should be entirely in the question.  We shouldn't need to click off-site to see your code.  What happens when that video disappears?  Your question would become useless to future readers.

Comment: OK, you've chosen a random colour and stored it in `c`. You could check `c == TintColors[0]` to see if it's the first one in the list. Or you could just say `transform.gameObject.tag = c.Name;`, assuming all your colors are named colours (and assuming we're talking about `System.Drawing.Color` here).

Answer (score 2):

If what you're asking is only to set the Game Object's tag to the name of the color that was set in your OnTriggerExit2D function, it's pretty simple:

```
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "ball")
    {
        Color c = TintColors[Random.Range(0, TintColors.Count)];        
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = c;

        // You have already determined what color is selected.
        // all you need do now is assign the string value of that color to the
        // colliding gameObject's tag property.
        col.gameObject.tag = c.ToString();
    }
}
```